# how to manually assign a Token to a user context in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to write my own Authorize filter to handle Token-Based authentications. 
[For some reasons i don't want to implement ASP.Net Identity authentication system]

I want to assign my own Generated token to a user context in WebApi.

something like what the ASP.net Identity does.

how can i do this manually ?

thanks.

Comment: `For some reasons i don't want to implement ASP.Net Identity authentication system` What are those reasons? _This stuff is **super** hard to get 100% right so I wouldn't do it if you really didn't have to._

Comment: i was started to learn asp.net identity. and i have implemented it for my webApi. but there was some issue about it and it takes me a lot of times to R&D :
1. i dont want to add some extra Tables in my database as the first issue.
2. i need to a mapping between users and tokens. in ASP.NET Identity, each login request will generates another valid Token. but i needed to limit this.
I want to use/create an easy to use, powerful Authentication method with a reasonable cost of learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by creating your own custom token provider class.

```
public class AccessTokenProvider : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken("yourtoken");
        base.Create(context);
    }
}
```

and setup your authorization option in owin startup class as below.

```
OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    AccessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProvider()
};

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
```

Comment: thanks. first i was trying to implement IAuthenticationTokenProvider but it fell on some exceptions. 
but still there is an exception. 
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions tries to fire CreateAsync function that returns a Task object at the end. but i don't know what should i return.

Comment: public override Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            context.SetToken("yourtoken");
            return base.CreateAsync(context);
        }